How can I solve the problem with pagination in vue?
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers float-end">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-rounded mb-0" v-if="personLeave">
        <b-pagination
        v-model="currentPage"
        :total-rows="personLeave.count"
        :per-page="perPage"
        ></b-pagination>
    </ul>
</div>

data() {
  userDetail: [],
  noUserFoundError: "",
  currentPage: 1,
  perPage: 5,
  personLeave: [],
};

I am new to vue. This is my code but pagination doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? I configure my pagination to display 5 rows per page but a second page is not displayed when the data rows are more than 5.

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Arrays don't have "count" in JS, it's "length". v-if="personLeave" is always true if personLeave is an array. It's unknown what you could do wrong else and what b-pagination is
